# import posts with dutch/special letters

Tags: plugins, database, import, phpmyadmin, bulk-import

I am importing posts from a csv file using the plugin [Really Simple CSV Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-csv-importer/). I am uploading some posts in dutch language.

The plugin uploads all the posts nicely but fails for the post which has special letters like the "ö" in "Beyersdörfer Gmbh". The "é" in "Alméér Plant" and so on.

I guess these characters is not supported by the database may be. If so can any one help me what settings do I need to change so that such letters are also supported.

Earlier also I had such issue. If I have such letters say in the title of a post, chrome shows it nicely but firefox does not show it in the title meta tag. So I used to replace such characters with the standard ones.

But right now my scenario is that I can't change it. So would like to know how to make the database support such letters.

May be change utf-8 to something...I don't know much about charset.